# i deploy my mern app in heroku website but frontend not working, please any solve this error and how to solve this error step by step?

Tags: node.js, heroku, mern

1. 2022-02-22T11:43:11.052931+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
   2022-02-22T11:43:11.127668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
   up to starting 2022-02-22T11:43:12.257086+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
   Stopping all processes with SIGTERM 2022-02-22T11:43:12.562513+00:00
   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
   2022-02-22T11:43:25.041006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process
   with command `npm start` 2022-02-22T11:43:27.469751+00:00
   app[web.1]: 2022-02-22T11:43:27.469804+00:00 app[web.1]: >
   chat-app@1.0.0 start 2022-02-22T11:43:27.469804+00:00 app[web.1]: >
   nodemon backend/server.js 2022-02-22T11:43:27.469804+00:00
   app[web.1]: 2022-02-22T11:43:28.178307+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon]
   2.0.15 2022-02-22T11:43:28.179512+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` 2022-02-22T11:43:28.191280+00:00
   app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
   2022-02-22T11:43:28.191408+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching
   extensions: js,mjs,json 2022-02-22T11:43:28.191955+00:00 app[web.1]:
   [nodemon] starting `node backend/server.js`
   **main error**
   Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
   Process exited with status 143

   ```
    **server.js**
     -  const express = require("express"); const connectDB = require("./config/db"); const dotenv = require("dotenv"); const
    userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes"); const chatRoutes =
    require("./routes/chatRoutes"); const messageRoutes =
    require("./routes/messageRoutes"); const { notFound, errorHandler }
    = require("./middleware/errorMiddleware"); const path = require("path");

    dotenv.config(); connectDB(); const app = express();

    app.use(express.json()); // to accept json data

    // app.get("/", (req, res) => { //   res.send("API Running!"); //
    });

    app.use("/api/user", userRoutes); app.use("/api/chat", chatRoutes);
    app.use("/api/message", messageRoutes);

    //
    --------------------------deployment------------------------------

    const __dirname1 = path.resolve();

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {  
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname1, "/frontend/build")));

      app.get("*", (req, res) =>
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname1, "frontend", "build", "index.html"))   ); } else {   app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.send("API is running..");   }); }

    //
    --------------------------deployment------------------------------

    // Error Handling middlewares app.use(notFound);
    app.use(errorHandler);

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    const server = app.listen(   PORT,   console.log(`Server running on
    PORT ${PORT}...`.yellow.bold) );

    const io = require("socket.io")(server, {   pingTimeout: 60000,  
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        // credentials: true,   }, });

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {   console.log("Connected to
    socket.io");   socket.on("setup", (userData) => {
        socket.join(userData._id);
        socket.emit("connected");   });

      socket.on("join chat", (room) => {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log("User Joined Room: " + room);   });   socket.on("typing", (room) => socket.in(room).emit("typing"));  
    socket.on("stop typing", (room) => socket.in(room).emit("stop
    typing"));

      socket.on("new message", (newMessageRecieved) => {
        var chat = newMessageRecieved.chat;

        if (!chat.users) return console.log("chat.users not defined");

        chat.users.forEach((user) => {
          if (user._id == newMessageRecieved.sender._id) return;
        enter code here

     1. List item

          socket.in(user._id).emit("message recieved", newMessageRecieved);
        });   });

      socket.off("setup", () => {
        console.log("USER DISCONNECTED");
        socket.leave(userData._id);   }); });

    ----------
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) There's a bunch of stuff mixed together here, lists where there shouldn't be lists, invalid non-code text in your code block, etc. which makes this question very hard to read. Please [edit] it to make it clearer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).